# What may be the issues using HTTP push for mobile devices/apps?

Tags: http, mobile, push-notification, server-push, mqtt

I have to devise a push notification plan for some mobile devices where push is not yet officially supported by C2DM / APNS / BES ,etc. MQTT was also a good option but I could not get an MQTT Client for my required platform. (Blackberry Playbook, ActionScript only)

Going back to basics, I had the options of Long Polling and streaming. Streaming using a high keep-alive value seems good to me, as the development of the mobile app (it is not a browser) and the server code are both in my control. To maintain the connection open, I just need to ping the server occasionally.

What issues I may be facing in this approach ? I understand this would constantly open an HTTP connection from the device to the server. Would the battery life of mobile device drain quickly just by persistently opening a server connection ? ...Afterall the data is not being transferred, just by keeping the connection open...right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) or take a look at this [realtime technologies guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide).

If realtime really matters, I'm talking about seconds or milliseconds, then a realtime web technology using [WebSockets](http://pusher.com/websockets) or [HTTP Streaming](http://www.quora.com/HTTP-Streaming) is your best option as they deliver updates the instant they are available. This sort of thing is best suited to the sort of application that a user is actively using during a reasonable period of time where they need instant notifications or are collaborating/chatting with others.

WebSockets are probably a better standard to be using with longer term technology considerations in mind since they are the first standard for full duplex bi-directional communication between a client (mobile, web, desktop) and server.

Answer (score 0):

What platform could you not find an MQTT client for?  http://mqtt.org/software lists clients in just about every language I can think of and more than I'd like to bother using.  The mosquitto C client library is *very* portable.

For battery life, it really depends what you're doing between the keepalives...

Comment: Playbook supports only ActionScript. I cant find a supported MQTT client in ActionScript

Answer (score 0):

If you app runs in a country where the network isn't in the best shape, then having all your clients keep a connection open can put strain on their infrastructure (assuming you are *that* popular).

Battery life is the other consideration, yes, a lot of devices aren't that efficient in keeping an idle radio/3g connection open and it drains the battery a lot faster than not having a connection open.